# How to give dynamic height to labels contained withing stackview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

Inside a `UITableView` cell I have the following structure.

[image: screenshot of UITableView structure]

It has two `UIStackView` instances, Left and Right

1. Left stack view contains 3 views. Each view containing 1 label (Label1, Label2, Label3)
2. Right stack view contains 2 views. Each view containing 1 label (Label5, Label6)

Constraints for Label1, Label2 and Label3 are Top, Left,  Right and Bottom with respect to its parent views.

Now when I add text to Label1, Label2 and Label3 at runtime it gives dynamic height but leaves space in top and bottom, for those label having less text. Below is the output.

[image: screenshot of cell dynamic height issue]

I want to reduce the top and bottom spaces for all the three labels i.e Label1, Label2, Label3.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I think You have use distribution of Stack view as fill equally so it gives equal space to each one.
I think for this you have to use fill proportionally. this will adjust height accordingly

[Choose fill proportionally from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbUKU.png)

```
if this not working then choose fill proportionally and give height to each label it will adjust.
```

Check how to give height to labels .
[image]

after giving each label height inside stack view like this .
your it will adjust itself according to data.Like this

[image]

Comment: If I apply fill proportionally then nothing is visible in Table view.

Comment: Check Constrains is it correct as this is working fine on my end.I think  you forgot to git height to each label .Give height to each label and make it greater then or equals to  then it will work fine

Comment: thanks for the reply @Amit. I have given the constraint as mentioned in my question. i.e (left, Right ,Top and Bottom) . But still it is not working.

Comment: No, you are not getting my point .I mean give height to each label  greater then or equal .I will update my above answer with two new screenshot please check.

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic height use self sizing cells in tableview. Set rowHeight and estimatedHeight properties for tableView

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

Set the stackview distribution property to `.fillproportionally`

as per the UIStackView [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/distribution) of .fillproportionally property

> A layout where the stack view resizes its arranged views so that they
>   fill the available space along the stack view’s axis. Views are
>   resized proportionally based on their intrinsic content size along the
>   stack view’s axis.

**in code:**

```
stackView.distribution = fillproportionally
```

or in storyboard

[image]

Comment: If I apply fill proportionally then nothing is visible in Table view not even right side stack view. what could be the reason?

Comment: set stackView.alignment = fill and check if it works

Comment: use self sizing cells for dynamic height.

Comment: already using self sizing cell :) but even that is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly go to main UIStackview height constraint edit option and set constant height greater than current constant height. After that you will set the label line number 0.

Now add tablewView row height delegate function and return **UITableView.Autodemenssion** height.

[image]